# AWS - SNS SMS Is not delivered for Special Services - New Zealand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

When I tried to send SMS with NZ country code prefix it is working fine.

But with Special services with a prefix of 020, 021, 022, 026, 027, 028 or 029 SMS is not getting delivered.

Can anyone help me, is there any special requirements to be followed like USA (10DLC) for NZ region ?

Answer (score 0):

Checked with AWS support team and they said many customers reported similar issue and they suggested to use short codes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-short-codes.html

But I tried to send with country code + 20****/21****/22****(Without 0) it worked for me.